# Opening JNLP within the browser

Tags: java, javafx, jnlp

I need to launch my JNLP application within the browser rather than getting downloaded separately when url is provided & opening it. Below is my jnlp file:

```xml
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:7077/ChqPrint/files/" href="JNLP_print.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Jnlp Testing</title>
        <vendor>xxx</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://localhost:7077/ChqPrint/files/" />
        <description>Testing </description>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+" />
        <jar href="resources/xxx.jar" main="true" />
        </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="com.scb.app.LaunchApplication" />
    <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

I have my jar file xxx.jar also. Below is my jsp file. My jnlp file is embedded in jsp and it's below.

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:7077/ChqPrint/files/" href="cheque_print.jsp">
    <information>
        <title>Jnlp Testing</title>
        <vendor>xxx</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://localhost:7077/ChqPrint/files/" />
        <description>Testing </description>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="resources/xxx.jar" main="true" />
        <!-- <jar href="resources/lib/jfxrt.jar" /> -->
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="com.scb.app.LaunchApplication">
        <argument><%=session.getId()%></argument>
        <argument><%=request.getServerName()%></argument>       
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

I usually launch my application using the url http://localhost:7077/ChqPrint/files/cheque_print.jsp
which will download my jnlp file as a standalone application.

Now the requirement is to open the jnlp within the browser & they don't want it to be opened separately. Any ideas on how to implement it?

Comment: You are asking about running your application as an *applet*, instead of running it via Java Web Start. You can still find [deployment instructions for this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/), but note that most browser vendors have already removed the plugin required to run Java for security reasons, and that Oracle will [deprecate the Java plugin](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/jdk9_plugin.xml) in the upcoming release. In short, running a Java application in a browser is no longer supported.

Comment: *"Any ideas on how to implement it?"* Step 1, invent a time machine.. The day of embedded rich client applets in HTML is fast closing (already closed in many browsers). @James_D gave one link, here are two more: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: @James_D Many Thanks for your suggestions !! I went across the url's shared & not working out when I created a new html file with the below contents. When I enter the url on IE, it is redirecting me to install Java 8. Once done Later, It is showing blank .Kindly assist. <script type="text/javascript" src="https://java.com/js/dtjava.js"></script>
    <body>
    <a href="JNLP_print.jnlp"  onclick="dtjava.launch(new dtjava.App('JNLP_print.jnlp')); 
        return false;">Launch me!</a>
    </body>
    
</html>

Comment: @AndrewThompson Is there any way to freeze the main browser until the standalone jnlp window is closed? My requirement is not to use applets & need to maintain session. If I launch my app as standalone, session cant be maintained. So it is asked to open the app within the browser so that integration becomes easy with existing webapp.

Comment: "Is there any way to freeze the main browser until the standalone jnlp window is closed?" Fortunately, no. It's nonsense like that, that got plug-ins removed from browsers in the first place! I don't know if any technology suits this requirement, but do know that Java is simply the **wrong technology to use here**.

Answer (score 2):

Specifically, look at section [5.9.2 Embed the Deployment Descriptor into the Web Page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packaging.html#BABCJCHH), which embeds the JNLP data in the web page.  This will generate [some JavaScript in the page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/deployment_toolkit.html#BABJHEJA) to invoke the Oracle Java browser plugin, which will launch the application directly into the browser (if the Oracle Java browser plugin is supported within your deployment environment).

As James mentioned in comments, the [Oracle Java plugin is soon to be deprecated](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/jdk9_plugin.xml) (and is currently either not supported or disabled by default in many browsers).  So, it is not recommended to use a deployment mode (Java Applet or JavaFX Application embedded and rendered within an HTML webpage) that supposes a working Oracle Java Plugin can be used by the application user.

If you want an app that runs in a browser, use browser based technologies, such as [HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info) and [Angular](https://angularjs.org) or some other combo of JavaScript based libraries that are popular in the day (just my opinion).